# Scrapy - filtering yielded items

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, xml-parsing, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape some items, as shown below:

```
def parse(self, response):

    item = GameItem()
    item['game_commentary'] = response.css('tr td:nth-child(2)[style*=vertical-align]::text').extract()
    item['game_movement'] = response.xpath("//tr/td[1][contains(@style,'vertical-align: top')]/text()").extract()

    yield item
```

My problem is that I don't want to `yield` all the items that current `response.xpath` or `response.css` selectors extracts.

Is there a way of, before assigning these commands to `item['game_commentary']` and `item['game_movement']`, applying a `regex` or something else to filter unwished values which are not to be yielded?

Comment: Isn't possible to filter unwished values with XPath ? XPath 2.0 supports regex if needed.

Comment: Didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) to accomplish this.
You'll have to rewrite your parsing as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
    loader = GameItemLoader(item=GameItem(), response=response)
    loader.add_css('game_commentary', 'tr td:nth-child(2)[style*=vertical-align]::text')
    loader.add_xpath('game_movement', "//tr/td[1][contains(@style,'vertical-align: top')]/text()")
    item = loader.load_item()
    yield item
```

Your items.py will look something like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst

class GameItemLoader(Item):
    # default input & output processors
    # will be executed for each item loaded,
    # except if a specific in or output processor is specified
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    # you can specify specific input & output processors per field
    game_commentary_in = '...'
    game_commentary_out = '...'

class GameItem(RetviewsItem):
    game_commentary = Field()
    game_movement = Field()
```

Comment: Interesting solution! As a beginner, there are still lot of features of scrapy I don't know. Thank you, Wim!